# How to format a Date inside the Telerik Grid Editor Popup

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, telerik

I am using a Popup Editor Template for my grid. I want to display the Report Date and want to know how I can format the date value to "yyyy/MM/dd".

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:3px">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      @(Html.LabelFor(r => r.ReportDate))
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      ${ReportDate}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(r => r.ReportDate, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")` have you tried this? is it working?

Comment: Hi, thank you, but you are speaking about the LABEL, but I want to format the Data part where I have ${ReportDate}

Comment: `ReportDate` is this coming from model?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have added the Data Annotations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anybody else with the same problem, the answer is very simple.
Use the kendo toString method in this way:

```
 ${kendo.toString(ReportDate, "yyyy/MM/dd")}
```

[Formats a Number or Date using the specified format and the current culture](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/tostring)